# How to get objects by index immutable.js

Tags: redux, immutable.js

In Immutable.js how can I get an object from a list by index and set a property then update the entire list.

the state is an array of objects named artists.

```
[{ id: 1, selected: false}, { id: 2, selected: false}]
```

Now I wish to set selected = true  at index 0

I tried:

```
  const artistItem = state.get(action.payload.index).set({ selected: true });
  const artists = state.get('artists').set(action.payload.index, artistItem);
```

How can I achieve this, without overwriting the other properties?

Answer (score 3):

If your state really does look like

```js
[{ id: 1, selected: false}, { id: 2, selected: false}]
```

I believe you want to use [List#update](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/update):

```js
let state = Immutable.fromJS([
    {id: 1, selected: false},
    {id: 2, selected: false}
]);

state = state.update(0, (artist) => artist.set('selected', true));
console.log(state); // [{id: 1, selected: true}, {id: 2, selected: false}]

// Note that this is equivalent to:
state = state.set(0, state.get(0).set('selected'));
```

But from your code it seems like your state actually looks more like

```js
{ artists: [{ id: 1, selected: false}, { id: 2, selected: false}] }
```

If this is the case, you will want to use [Map#updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn):

```js
let state = Immutable.fromJS({
    artists: [
       {id: 1, selected: false},
       {id: 2, selected: false}
    ]
});

state = state.updateIn(['artists', 0], (artist) => artist.set('selected', true));
console.log(state); //{artists: [{id: 1, selected: true}, {id: 2, selected: false}]

// Note that this is equivalent to:
state = state.set(
  'artists',
  state.get(artists).set(
    0,
    state.get(artists).get(0).set('selected', true)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

`ImmutableList.set()` returns another list with the changes.
This is the proper way to modify an item:

```
const index = action.payload.index
const newArtists = state.set(index, { ...state.get(index), selected: true });
...
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that i have other properties in the objects. This will replace all the properties. I wish to update the specific property. I edited the ticket

Comment: What's the result

Comment: state.get(index) returns undefined in { ...state.get(index), selected: true });

Comment: Because the state might not have such an index. Try checking first

Comment: the index is actually there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157610/discussion-between-alexander-vitanov-and-user1526912).